# cordova blackberry 10 can't deploy to device

Tags: macos, cordova, blackberry, blackberry-10

I followed instructions from the phonegap [platform guides](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_blackberry10_index.md.html#BlackBerry%2010%20Platform%20Guide) to create a hello world app and deploy to BB10. Had no problems with Android or iOS, but when I try to run the app on a BB10 I get this output:

```
$ platforms/blackberry10/cordova/run --device --keystorepass passhere --devicepass devicepasshere

[INFO]    Target Z30-2ba65880 selected
[INFO]    The existing debug token is valid
[INFO]    Deploying debug token to target "Z30-2ba65880"
[INFO]    Sending request: INSTALL_DEBUG_TOKEN
[INFO]    Action: Install Debug Token
[INFO]    File size: 2645
[INFO]    result::success
[INFO]    Populating application source
[INFO]    Parsing config.xml
[INFO]    Generating output files
[INFO]    Package created: /Users/adriaan/Documents/phonegap/hello/platforms/blackberry10/build/simulator/bb10app.bar
[INFO]    Package created: /Users/adriaan/Documents/phonegap/hello/platforms/blackberry10/build/device/bb10app.bar
[INFO]    BAR packaging complete
[INFO]    Sending request: INSTALL_AND_LAUNCH
[INFO]    Action: Install and Launch
[INFO]    File size: 78983
[INFO]    Installing com.example.hello.testDev_ample_hellodf4765a1...
[INFO]    Processing 78983 bytes
[INFO]    actual_dname::actual_id::
[INFO]    actual_version::result::failure 500 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 120: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I've tried this on Mountain Lion and Mavericks. On Mountain Lion I had the native and webworks sdks installed, on Mavericks only the Web Works.

Comment: i also face same issue. have you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your project some data is not correctly encoded as UTF-8. Check your filenames and file content for non UTF-8 characters and make sure you escape or replace them.

Answer (score 0):

I face same issue please follow below step i resolve this issue by change the author name from bar-descriptor.xml

**solution 1)**

changed the author simply to "Julian Buss", recreated the debug token, cleaned the project and then I could run it on the device. Problem solved. [click here](https://www.blackberry.com/jira/browse/BBTEN-2754?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel)

**solution 2)**

Remove debug token from your device or simulator please follow below step

1)  goto **Setting->Security and Privacy->Development Mode->** click on **remove debug token button**(This button is display if and only if you have install any debug token )

2)  if you have not install debug token then regenerate debug token and install it.

I hope this will work This solution is work for me.